# Как получить объект из JSON

Tags: java, json

```
String jsonString = "{\"result\":{\"ID\":\"1\"}}"
```

Сейчас я делаю следующим образом:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.USE_JAVA_ARRAY_FOR_JSON_ARRAY, true);
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNRESOLVED_OBJECT_IDS, false);
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String result = jsonObj.getString("result");

MyClass myClass = objectMapper.readValue(result, MyClass.class);
```

MyClass.java

```
public class MyClass {
    private String id;

    public String getid() {
        return id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("ID")
    public void setid(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

А как парсить MyClass в jsonString без предварительного выделения result?

А то у меня нет уверенности, что "завтра" вместо result может что-то другое быть.

Answer (score 1):

По идее вам надо просто 2 класса модели создать. Один для внешнего объекта, один для внутреннего. И парсить весь объект как внешний.

```
public class MyOuterClass {
    private MyClass result;

    public MyClass getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    @JsonProperty("result")
    public void setResult(MyClass result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
}
```

```
MyOuterClass myOuterClass = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, MyOuterClass.class);
```

Comment: Ну вот от этого я и пытаюсь уйти. Нужен инструмент, который будет сам искать в json честь, соответствующую классу MyClass и парсить его.

Comment: Ребята, присылающие json ответ, не надежные. Это на тот случай, если вдруг MyClass придет не в составе result, а в составе чего-то еще...

Comment: @VitalyM., вроде бы готовых решений для этого нет. Получается, надо просто руками рекурсивно обходить весь JSON ища объект с ключом `ID` и его уже парсить в качестве нужного вам класса. Что тоже, конечно, никаких гарантий не даст, но, наверное, в вашем случае только это и остаётся)